# Lexer that can be used in debug mode or in operational mode

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am reading a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139328645) that has a nifty way of designing a lexer so that, when DEBUG is defined, it outputs `token is value` for each token. I have a simple lexer that has a rule for a `NAME` and a rule for a `NUM`. If the input is this:

```
Sally 30
```

and `DEBUG` is defined, then the output should show this:

```
NAME is "Sally"
NUM is "30"
```

Below is the lexer. Unfortunately, when I run the lexer (with `DEBUG` set), I get this output:

```
x is "Sally"
x is "30"
```

That is, I see the token value but not the token name. What am I doing wrong?

Also, there is one part of the code that I just can't figure out what it's doing:

```
#define Return(x)   return yylval = x, 1
```

What is that doing? Is it assigning `x` to `yylval` and then returning `1`?

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#ifdef DEBUG
   int yylex(void);
   char * yylval;
   
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   { 
      yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      while (yylex())
         printf("%-.10s is \"%s\"\n", yylval, yytext);
      fclose(yyin);
      return 0;
   }
   
#define token(x)    "x"
#define Return(x)   return yylval = x, 1

#else

#define token(x)    x
#define Return(x)   return x

#endif
%}
%%
[ \t]+      { /* ignore whitespace */ }
[a-zA-Z]+   {
#ifndef DEBUG
              yyval.strval = strdup(yytext);
#endif 
              Return(token(NAME)); 
            }
[0-9]+      { 
#ifndef DEBUG
              yyval.intval = atoi(yytext);
#endif
              Return(token(NUM)); 
            }
%%
```

Comment: Please throw that book away.

Comment: Bison's trace facility shows you what the parser sees from the lexer. (See the `%printer` bison directive for additional info.) Flex's debug facility will print out the string matched by each rule, along with the pattern's line number. You might want to enable both.

Comment: (I've never seen that book so I'm just going by the code excerpt you pasted. But any book which purports to teach you C but does not know how to use the preprocessor stringify operator cannot be trusted.)

Comment: I haven't used the book that @roger mentions, but the same author (Schreiner) wrote [the Unicorn book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Compiler-Construction-Prentice-Hall-software/dp/0134743962), which I found to be quite helpful, back in the day.

Comment: Thank you @David Gorsline I just purchased the Unicorn book.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at a footnote in the book, I discovered the correct approach. It is wicked cool. See code below.

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#ifdef DEBUG
   int yylex(void);
   char * yylval;
   
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   { 
      yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      while (yylex())
         printf("%-.10s is \"%s\"\n", yylval, yytext);
      fclose(yyin);
      return 0;
   }
   
#define Return(x)   return yylval = #x, 1

#else

#define Return(x)   return x

#endif
%}
%%
[ \t]+      { /* ignore whitespace */ }
[a-zA-Z]+   {
#ifndef DEBUG
              yyval.strval = strdup(yytext);
#endif 
              Return(NAME); 
            }
[0-9]+      { 
#ifndef DEBUG
              yyval.intval = atoi(yytext);
#endif
              Return(NUM); 
            }
%%
```